# Type Safe Proxy Creation

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Imagine I have two methods:

```
private <T> T testGenericsT(Class<T> clazz) {
    Class[] classArray = {clazz};
    return (T) newProxyInstance(
        clazz.getClassLoader(),
        classArray,
        (proxy, method, args) -> null
    );
  }
```

and:

```
private AccessibleStreamable testGenerics(Class<AccessibleStreamable> clazz) {
    Class[] classArray = { clazz };
    return (AccessibleStreamable) newProxyInstance(
        clazz.getClassLoader(),
        classArray,
        (proxy, method, args) -> null
    );
  }
```

The upper one is not type safe, I get the warning

> unchecked cast java.lang.Object to T

But the lower one is accepted, from my point of view I'm not sure where these differs. Is there a way I can make the upper one typesafe?

What am I missing here, why is it perfectly fine to cast it to a AccessibleStreamable but not T?

I can even change my code like this

```
  private AccessibleStreamable testGenerics(Class<AccessibleStreamable> clazz) {
    Class[] classArray = { List.class };
    return (AccessibleStreamable) newProxyInstance(
        Map.class.getClassLoader(),
        classArray,
        (proxy, method, args) -> null
    );
  }
```

And it will still not say any warning. Of course I wouldn't expect it to give me a warning saying that I'm doing an unchecked cast to T.

But I guess my main question is, is there a way I can make the upper one safe?  ( and I don't mean by suppressing the warning )

Comment: No, there's no way, due to type erasure. That's what the warning says: there is no way to make the cast to T fail if the object is not an instance of T, because T is erased at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The cast to `(T)` is not necessarily unsafe (it's still a cast though). The warning just means that there is no actual cast *at that point*, because there is no built-in reference to the actual class of `T`.

I see you're also passing a `Class<T>` to the method. You can use that to manually perform a checked cast at that point, similar to your second snippet:

```
private <T> T testGenericsT(Class<T> clazz) {
    Class<?>[] classArray = {clazz};
    return clazz.cast(newProxyInstance(
        clazz.getClassLoader(),
        classArray,
        (proxy, method, args) -> null
    ));
}
```

Comment: The Class<T> is something I get from Spring so it's outside of my control, but thank you for this answer. I've previously used things like ParameterizedType to find what value is inside an Optional and similar things, and was thinking if there was something similar I could do here.

Comment: @nesohc But a ParameterizedType returns a `Type[]` for the actual parameters. A `Class` is also a `Type`, so you're already there. I don't really see what you mean by that?

Comment: It was a bad example, I just meant if I could access it somehow. And I meant it as an example for what I did with ParameterizedType, by casting it, I got access to other methods to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple:

*from my point of view I'm not sure where these differs.*

The first example uses a **generic** type parameter T. That can be **anything**.

The second example uses **one** explicit class name (AccessibleStreamable).

And of course: because of *[type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)*, that type T ... doesn't exist at runtime. Whereas the second method has a fixed type, that it is no problem to cast.